# Optimising for loop

Tags: javascript, optimization

I have a JavaScript program which seems to take a long time going through the below for loop.

```
    let store = [];
    for (var i = 0; i<area.length; i++) {
        if (area.lastIndexOf(area[i]) === area.indexOf(area[i])) {
            store.push([area[i], price[i]]);
        }
        else {
            const compList = price.filter((_,j) => {
                const state = area[j] === area[i] && j!==i;
                return state; 
            });
            let mean = compList.reduce((a,b)=>a+b,0) / compList.length;
            let std = compList.reduce((a,b)=>a+(b-mean)**2/compList.length,0) ** 0.5;
            Math.abs(mean-price[i]) <= 3 * std && store.push([area[i],price[i]]);
        }
    }
```

I suspect a recursive solution might perform better, but not sure how to design it.

Comment: do you have some data as well? what is the wanted result?

Comment: I believe Nina was looking for some actual data (ideally a set just large enough to show the behavior), along with the result you expect from it, although we should be able to run it to determine the output.

Comment: There are some clear inefficiencies here.  Minor: you do the division in every step of the standard deviation, rather than once, after the summation.  Major: you calculate the mean/stdDev for every entry.  You should group them and calculate the outliers for each group with only one mean/stdDev call per group.

Comment: Are the area and price arrays just the elements in the first column, separated by `/`?

Comment: Your final `Math.abs(...)` line of code appears to be a convoluted way of writing an `if` statement. Why make it less readable?

Comment: I'm not much of a statistician, but does it make sense to calculate `mean/stdDev` based without the one you're trying to classify as an outlier?  Shouldn't you include them in the calculation?  A value is an outlier if it's at least three standard deviations away from the mean of *the whole group*, not from the mean of *the rest of the group*, no?  The current solution means that groups of two are both outliers, even if they are identical, which is weird.

Comment: 50,000 houses spread over approximately how many areas?  Those two numbers should give the algorithmic complexity of your algorithm.

Comment: *`for (var i = 0; i<area.length; i++) { if (area.lastIndexOf(area[i]) === area.indexOf(area[i]))  …  compList = price.filter((_,j) => area[j] === area[i] && j!==i) …}`* is a ridiculously slow way to find duplicates, with quadratic complexity, which matters a lot if you have large arrays. Instead, build a `Map` keyed by area with an array of prices as the value, and then process that.

Comment: I will look at code soon, if I can.  The first one is trivial to fix, but the second one will be harder, especially if I can't convince you to include the current value when testing it for outliers.  :-).  What I mean above, is how many unique areas?

Comment: I don't understand "about 50%" here.  If that means there are approximately 25,000 areas, and the average area has only two houses, then testing for outliers is meaningless.

Comment: Also, your output is, I assume, `store` which is a list of area/price pairs that are *not* outliers.  Does this have to be in the same relative order as the input?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here we do two solutions.  Both depend on two helper functions.  `sum` totals an array of numbers.  And `groupBy` -- which you'll find in many utility libraries, takes a function and groups the elements into an object whose keys are the results of calling that function with your data and whose corresponding values are all the elements of your input list that result in the particular key.  For instance,

```
groupBy (x => x % 10) ([21, 15, 11, 3, 5, 1, 7])
//=> {"1": [21, 11, 1], "3": [3], "5": [15, 5], "7": [7]}
```

We use this to consolidate all the prices for an area.  In both solutions, we do this first on your data, then flatten the resulting object into an array of area/priceList values such as this:

```js
[[1200, [12000, 14000, 13000]], [1300, [24000, 22000]], [2000, [30000]]]
```

Our first solution -- and my preference -- is to then *include* the current item when calculating the outliers.  This makes more logical sense to me (why would every group of two include two outliers, for instance?) and is both easier to calculate and more performant.  It looks like this:

```js
const groupBy = (fn) => (xs) => 
  xs .reduce ((g, x, i, _, k = fn (x, i)) => ((g [k] = g [k] || []), (g [k] .push (x)), g), {})

const sum = (ns) =>
  ns .reduce ((a, b) => a + b, 0)

const getNonOutliers = (area, price) => {
  const groups = Object .entries (groupBy ((_, i) => area [i]) (price)) 
                        .map (([k, v]) => [Number(k), v])
  
  return groups .flatMap (([area, price]) => {
    const mean = sum (price) / price .length
    const stdDev = (sum (price .map (p => (p - mean) ** 2)) / price .length) ** 0.5
    return price .filter (p => Math .abs (p - mean) <= 3 * stdDev) 
                 .map (price => [area, price])
  })
}

const area = [1200, 1300, 1200, 1300, 1200, 2000]
const price = [12000, 24000, 14000, 22000, 13000, 30000]

console .log (getNonOutliers (area, price))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

But if we want to avoid including the current item in that calculation (which is what's done in the original ill-performant code), then we can do this:

```js
const groupBy = (fn) => (xs) => 
  xs .reduce ((g, x, i, _, k = fn (x, i)) => ((g [k] = g [k] || []), (g [k] .push (x)), g), {})

const sum = (ns) =>
  ns .reduce ((a, b) => a + b, 0)

const getNonOutliers = (area, price) => {
  const groups = Object .entries (groupBy ((_, i) => area [i]) (price)) 
          .map (([k, v]) => [Number (k), v])
  
  return groups .flatMap (([area, price]) => {
    if (price .length == 1) {return [[area, price[0]]]}
    const total = sum (price)
    return price .filter ((p, i) => {
      const mean = (total - p) / (price .length - 1)
      const stdDev = (sum (price .map ((p, j) => j == i ? 0 : (p - mean) ** 2)) / (price .length - 1)) ** 0.5
      return Math .abs (p - mean) <= 3 * stdDev 
    }) .map (price => [area, price])
  })
}

const area = [1200, 1300, 1200, 1300, 1200, 2000]
const price = [12000, 24000, 14000, 22000, 13000, 30000]

console .log (getNonOutliers (area, price))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

In this solution, I've tried to make the `mean` calculation slightly more performant, by precalculating `total` and subtracting the current one.  This is pointless if the areas are small, and we could simply move the full mean calculation inside the inner call in that case.

I haven't done the benchmarking to even show that this would be faster than your approach, but I'm quite certain the first one -- and Bergi's similar solution -- would be significantly faster.  This depends on grouping like items first and not redoing the calculations per group.

The second one may have no significant performance advantage, though, as we have to do the calculations repeatedly.

---

There is one minor performance enhancement mentioned in the comments, which is simply the logical difference between:

```js
sum (xs) / xs .length
```

and

```js
sum (xs .map (x => x / xs .length))
```

We can do this division just once at the end, rather than on each step of totaling.

Comment: I forgot to mention, this solution does not maintain your original order.  It would be somewhat more complex to do so, although not horrible.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> for (var i = 0; i<area.length; i++) {
>   if (area.lastIndexOf(area[i]) === area.indexOf(area[i])) …
>   compList = price.filter((_,j) => area[j] === area[i] && j!==i)
>   …
> }
> ```

is a ridiculously slow way to find duplicates, with quadratic complexity, which matters a lot if you have large arrays. Instead, build a `Map` keyed by area with an array of prices as the value:

```
const pricesByArea = new Map();
for (let i=0; i<area.length; i++) {
  let prices = pricesByArea.get(area[i]);
  if (!prices) pricesByArea.set(area[i], prices = []);
  prices.push(price[i]);
}
```

and then process that:

```
const store = [];
for (const [area, prices] of pricesByArea) {
  if (compList.length == 1) {
    store.push([area, compList[0]]);
  } else {
    for (const [i, price] of prices.entries()) {
      const compList = prices.filter((_, j) => i != j);
      const mean = compList.reduce((a,b)=>a+b,0) / compList.length;
      const std = compList.reduce((a,b)=>a+(b-mean)**2/compList.length,0) ** 0.5;
      if (Math.abs(mean-price) <= 3 * std) {
        store.push([area, price]);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

(apart from order in `store`, this will have the same output as your original code)

You probably want a less weird definition of the `mean` for each group of prices in one area though:

```
const store = [];
for (const [area, prices] of pricesByArea) {
  if (prices.length == 1) {
    store.push([area, prices[0]]);
  } else {
    const mean = prices.reduce((a,b)=>a+b,0) / prices.length;
    const std = prices.reduce((a,b)=>a+(b-mean)**2/prices.length,0) ** 0.5;
    for (const price of prices)
      if (Math.abs(mean-price) <= 3 * std)
        store.push([area, price]);
  }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't have the same output as the original with the example given.  The results here will include all six elements, but two of them should be excluded (because of the oddity I discussed above about excluding the current value from the `mean` and `stdDev` calculations.  I think this makes more sense, though.

Comment: @ScottSauyet Ah, now I see what you meant by that comment, I didn't even realise that bug

Comment: It's an odd decision to my mind to do this, but there is no universal definition of outlier, so it's not horribly unreasonable.  Any multiple of the standard deviation will be problematic with enough data points.  I'm about to post my own, somewhat similar answers, one with the same behavior as this and one as requested.

Comment: @user Yes, like Scott mentioned I did change the processing a bit. Now updated the answer with both versions